# MacOS IVR SIP client

Tags: mac, sip

I'm looking for a SIP client that provides IVR functionality on MacOS X. Is there something like that?

Max

Answer (score 0):

I dont know any SIP client for Windows that implements a kind of IVR, i used a proprietary (from the company that i worked) software that implements the SIP server function. Are you already looked for Zoiper for MAC or something like that???

Comment: Does Zoiper have an auto answering mode where it listens for DTMF?